# Passing List of Data from Controller to View using ViewBag not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

From Controller I am passing a list of Batch using ViewBag to the View, and this is running well . Code for this is given below:

Controller Code:

```
  [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult RegisterForProgrammingContest()
            {

                List<SelectListItem> Batch = GetBatch();

                ViewBag.Batch = Batch;

                return View();
            }




            private List<SelectListItem> GetBatch()
            {


                List<SelectListItem>batch = new List<SelectListItem>
                {

                    new SelectListItem {Text = "39th", Value = "39"},
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "40th", Value = "40"},
                    new SelectListItem{Text = "41st",Value = "41"}

                };



                return batch;
            }
```

View Code:

```
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Batch, new {@class = "text-success"})
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Batch, ViewBag.Batch as SelectList, new {@class = "form-control", @style = "width:250px"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Batch)
```

But when I am trying to pass a list of departments alongside with the list of batch using ViewBag. I am getting an error. My Modified Code is given Below:

Controller Code:

```
            [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult RegisterForProgrammingContest()
            {

                List<SelectListItem> Batch = GetBatch();

                ViewBag.Batch = Batch;

                List<SelectListItem> Department = GetDepartment();
                ViewBag.Department = Department;


                return View();
            }




            private List<SelectListItem> GetBatch()
            {



                List<SelectListItem>batch = new List<SelectListItem>
                {

                    new SelectListItem {Text = "39th", Value = "39"},
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "40th", Value = "40"},
                    new SelectListItem{Text = "41st",Value = "41"},
                    new SelectListItem{Text = "42nd",Value = "42"},
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "43rd", Value = "43"},
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "44th", Value = "44"},
                    new SelectListItem{Text = "45th",Value = "45"},
                    new SelectListItem{Text = "46th",Value = "46"}




                };



                return batch;
            }

            private List<SelectListItem> GetDepartment()
            {



                List<SelectListItem> department = new List<SelectListItem>
                {

                    new SelectListItem {Text = "CSE", Value = "CSE"},
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "IIT", Value = "IIT"},
                    new SelectListItem{Text = "Others",Value = "Others"}




                };



                return department;
            }
```

And View Code For this is :

```
 <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Batch, new {@class = "text-success"})
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Batch, ViewBag.Batch as SelectList, new {@class = "form-control", @style = "width:250px"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Batch)


                    </div>

                </div>


            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-12">

                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectDepartment, new { @class = "text-success" })
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectDepartment, ViewBag.Department as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:250px" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectDepartment)


                </div>

            </div>
```

I am getting the following error:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type'IEnumerable' that has the key 'SelectDepartment'.

Comment: Because `List<SelectListItem>` is NOT `SelectList` - its  `ViewBag.Batch as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and `ViewBag.Department as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

Comment: then should I change  List<SelectListItem>  to IEnumerable<SelectListItem>  ?? @StephenMuecke

Comment: Both will work. But what you should be doing is to stop using `ViewBag` and use a view model (which will contain a property `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`)

Comment: I can't get it. How should I implement it here in my code?

Comment: Change your view code exactly as per my first comment! - it need to be `ViewBag.Batch as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` or `(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Batch`,  not `ViewBag.Batch as SelectList` and ditto for the other dropdownlist

Comment: Thanks , it worked :) @StephenMuecke